# jquery apply an attribute to only the first element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set an a name to the first link with a specific class, but I'm kinda unsure as to how to apply something to just the first one?

So, I'm trying to find the first div with the sample class and then wrap the text within the div.title with the :

```
<div class="sample">
<div class="title"><a name="thisone">title</a></div>
<p>blah blah</p>
</div>

<div class="sample">
<div class="title">title</div>
<p>blah blah</p>
</div>

<div class="sample">
<div class="title">title</div>
<p>blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I love how the question requirements are so unclear that there are three answers here that do completely different things. You might want to provide before and after code in order to make clear what the desired Javascript should do.

Comment: pssst... @Matchu I think the snarky comment was directed at you. ;)

Comment: Heh. I was really being more critical of the answerers (self included) than the question. It took me three different edits to get to one that I thought met the requirements, mainly because I was tired. I started by answering the question title, then the code block, then the question's description. How tired must I be to do that? xD

Comment: In fact, it was so unintentional that it took me a while to figure out what y'all meant :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$("div.sample:first div.title").contents().wrap("<a name='thisone'></a>");
```

It finds the first `<div>` with class `sample`. Inside it finds the divs with class `title` and wraps their contents in a link.

Answer (score 0):

Will that `<a>` be there already? If so:

```
$('.sample:first .title a').attr('name', 'thisone');
```

If you don't have the `<a>` there to start with and want to wrap it in, use this:

```
$('.sample:first .title').wrap('<a name="thisone" />')
```

[(live example)](http://jsbin.com/acasa/edit)

Answer (score -2):

You need something like:

```
$('a:first').attr('name', 'thisone');
```